# ValueError: X has 1 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 2 features as input

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using pywebio to create a small script-run user interface for my machine learning program. When not using the small UI, I don't have any errors when running the linear regression `predict()` function.

The UI is retrieving two numbers from a user, an `'age'` and a `'salary'`. Those two numbers are entered into a numpy array, and the numpy array has been reshaped from a 1D array to a 2D array as I was receiving an error on the numpy array shape.

Now, I'm getting an error message on the `predict()` method only receiving 1 feature instead of 2, when sklearn documentation states that the linear regression `predict()` method is always getting 'self' and one other feature. How can I fix this error?

Here's my code for the UI:

```py
age = int(input("Enter your age:", type=NUMBER))
salary = int(input("Enter your salary:", type=NUMBER))

entry = np.array([age, salary])
reshaped_entry = entry.reshape(-1, 1)

estimate = regr.predict(reshaped_entry)
```

Here is the error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [21], in <cell line: 22>()

Input In [21], in retirement_ui()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py:362, in LinearModel.predict(self, X)
    348 def predict(self, X):
    349     """
    350     Predict using the linear model.
    351 
   (...)
    360         Returns predicted values.
    361     """
--> 362     return self._decision_function(X)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py:345, in LinearModel._decision_function(self, X)
    342 def _decision_function(self, X):
    343     check_is_fitted(self)
--> 345     X = self._validate_data(X, accept_sparse=["csr", "csc", "coo"], reset=False)
    346     return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T, dense_output=True) + self.intercept_

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:585, in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    582     out = X, y
    584 if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):
--> 585     self._check_n_features(X, reset=reset)
    587 return out

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:400, in BaseEstimator._check_n_features(self, X, reset)
    397     return
    399 if n_features != self.n_features_in_:
--> 400     raise ValueError(
    401         f"X has {n_features} features, but {self.__class__.__name__} "
    402         f"is expecting {self.n_features_in_} features as input."
    403     )

ValueError: X has 1 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 2 features as input.
```

Comment: I am not sure, but i think your reshape needs to be `reshaped_entry = entry.reshape(-1, 2)`. If you do it the way you're doing it, you're giving a batch size of 2 rather than a feature size of 2.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and got the following error: UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [19], in <cell line: 22>()

Input In [19], in retirement_ui()

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U66'), dtype('float64')) -> None

Comment: Cast it to float.

Comment: Well, darn. Casting to float generates the following error:          TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [19], in <cell line: 24>()

Input In [19], in retirement_ui()

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Estimate will be of shape `(1,1)`. So you'll need to print `estimate[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

The LinearRegression model was trained on data with 2 columns (presumably `age` and `salary`), so any new data to be fed into `predict()` method must have 2 columns as well. The error is basically saying the model needs an input with 2 features/columns.

To make it work, the reshaping method call should be `.reshape(1, -1)`.

A complete example to illustrate the point:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
import numpy as np

X, y = make_regression(n_features=2)
regr = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
entry = np.array([5, 50])

reshaped_entry = entry.reshape(-1, 1)      # <---- ValueError
reshaped_entry = entry.reshape(1, -1)      # <---- OK
estimate = regr.predict(reshaped_entry)
```

---

This is because given an array that looks like `array([5, 50])`, `.reshape(-1, 1)` transforms it into the following (a single column / column vector):

```py
array([[ 5],
       [50]])
```

while `.reshape(1, -1)` transforms it into (two columns / row vector):

```py
array([[ 5, 50]])
```

which is the desired shape.

---

If you get the same error but with unexpectedly high number of features such as

```
ValueError: X has 1 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 5 features as input.
```

then it's possible that you fed an incorrectly shaped input into the model in the first place especially if the input should have a single feature.

The following example illustrates this point. Instead of an array of shape (5,1), that of shape (1,5) is passed to the model so that the model now expects 5 features instead of 1. Then when we try to make a prediction using 1 feature, we get an error. To fix the issue, re-fit the model with the correctly shaped input.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

ar = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 3], [4, 5], [5, 6]]).to_numpy()

X, y = [ar[:, 0]], [ar[:, 1]]            # <--- wrong shaped X (shape=(1, 5))
regr = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
estimate = regr.predict([[22500]])       # <--- ValueError

X, y = ar[:, [0]], ar[:, 1]              # <--- correct shaped X (shape=(5, 1))
regr = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
estimate = regr.predict([[22500]])       # <--- OK
```